# Version Control Proxy with Multiple Servers TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, proxy

Is there a way to set up TFS to use multiple proxy servers? It's apparently one of the exam questions for the MS 496 exam, but I don't see any solution on the Web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup as many proxy servers as you wish.  You simply use the TFS Install Media to install the Proxy Server and configure it to point to the appropriate TFS Server.

The install instructions can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee259690.aspx

Comment: Awesome, this is perfect! Thank you, Dylan!!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK a proxy points at a collection (in TFS) and not at the TFS instance itself. I've never thought about pointing more than one proxy at a collection but you should be able to (as per Dylan's answer).